# FirebaseInstanceId error Android Studio when I compiled

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I'm have a problem with Android Studio. When I build apk, a error appears

> /Users/luisabsg/Downloads/FoodOn_FoodDelivery_by_Androrealm-master/app/src/main/java/com/food_on/apertivo/ChefFoodPanel_BottomNavigation.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
> import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
> ^
> symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceId
> location: package com.google.firebase.iid

[image]

How I can to solve?

Comment: this class is deprecated see this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId

Comment: @Burhan Khanzada I don't know where I change and what I change :(

Comment: i have downloaded and run that app on my end and its works maybe u have updated the dependencies of firestore that why its showing deprecated

Comment: @Burhan Khanzada do u want my code project to test?

Comment: ok drop your repo link i will evaluate your project